# Even after open with getting I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python-3.x, text, io

I am trying to use Python 3.6 to copy the lines written in "file1.txt" into another file, "file2.txt" just changing something in the name. The code I am using to do this is:

```
with open('path_to_file1', 'r') as fin:
    with open('path_to_file2', 'w') as fout:
        for line in fin:
            fout.write(line.replace('ending_file1', 'ending_file2'))
```

But I am getting the error "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file." Does anyone know why this could be happening? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I will advice that you check the indentation of your code first. And then make sure you include the right extension for your file (if necessary). The indentation after the first 'with' does not seem even with the indentation of the for statement. This may result in I/O value error. After restructuring your code, it works well for me:

```
with open('path_to_file1.txt', 'r') as fin:
    with open('path_to_file2.txt', 'w') as fout:
        for line in fin:
            fout.write(line.replace('ending_file1', 'ending_file2'))
```

Comment: Thanks! I am actually running all these in command line. My indentation is fine, but is still not working. I actually noticed that when I try to print some statement from command line, I get the same error "I/O operation on closed file". Do you know why this is happening with simple print statements?

Comment: I will advise that you use the command line for simple tasks and use a python IDE for more complex tasks. I am not sure why a print statement will result in a value error since values result from unexpected received 'values' (could be empty). From the piece of code you provided, it should work well from the correction. An important thing to note is that you will also get this error if you close the file in the for loop. Your code snippet doesn't show where you close the file so please make sure that it is indented outside the for loop scope.